# How can I test an SQL's UPDATE operation with JUnit?

Tags: java, jdbc, thymeleaf, junit4

I'm using thymeleaf and JDBC. I have this method that updates a Job object which contains a query.
How can I test this using JUnit?

```
public int updateJob(Job job){
  MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters=new MapSqlParameterSource();
  String sql1 = "UPDATE jobs SET title = :title, tool1 = :tool1 , tool2= :tool2 WHERE id = :id";  
  namedParameters.addValue("title", job.getTitle());
  namedParameters.addValue("tool1", job.getTool1());
  namedParameters.addValue("tool2", job.getTool2());
  namedParameters.addValue("id", job.getId());
  int rValue=jdbc.update(sql1, namedParameters);
  return rValue;
}
```

I also have the following method:

```
public int createJob(Job job){
  String sql1="INSERT INTO jobs (employee, title, tool1, tool2) VALUES(:employee, :title, :tool1, :tool2)";
  namedParameters.addValue("title", job.getTitle());
  namedParameters.addValue("tool1", job.getTool1());
  namedParameters.addValue("tool2", job.getTool2());
  namedParameters.addValue("id", job.getId());
  int rValue=jdbc.update(sql1, namedParameters);
  return rValue;
}
```

So I suppose I need to use the createJob() first, then updateJob() and somehow compare the resulting values???

Answer (score 0):

What's the level of your tests?

For unit tests, if be strongly surprised, if a database was involved.  The test would be to make sure *that* the correct update statement has been generated. If you test for actual data, it'd be hard to isolate against other test cases. And you'd unit test the database. Mocking the database can help.

For integration tests, you'd make sure that your database is in the state you expect when you execute this test. It's a matter of proper setup and tearDown.

Comment: To be honest all I understand is I need to check if the update was made or not.
Professor didn't dive into any details by only saying include a JUNIT for all methods in 'Xyz' class.

Comment: No, mocking would imply that you make sure _that the right update statement was *sent* to the database_. You assume that the database does the right thing with it. You're testing your code, the database is out of scope for _your_ test.

Comment: So all I should check is the type of data that is being send to the "database"?

Comment: That's _one way_ to do it. In a _Unit-Test_, you test your code, not the database. And you're doing it with as few external dependencies as possible. But as you have no more than an arbitrary and interpretable task ("use JUnit" as opposed to "include a unit test" vs "include an integration test"), I can't tell you what your professor expects.